What is the precise range of $s$ for which the system undergoes BEC at a non-zero temperature?
In a 3D ideal Bose gas, the energy-momentum relation is given $ \epsilon \propto p^s $ for $s>0$. The system may undergo Bose-Einstein condensation (BEC) at a non-zero temperature if the integral for the total number of particles in the excited states converges.
The density of states (DOS) is proportional to:
$$g(\epsilon) \propto \epsilon^{\frac{3}{s} - 1}.$$The total number of particles in the excited states is given by: $$N = \int_0^\infty \frac{g(\epsilon)}{e^{\epsilon / k_B T} - 1} \, d\epsilon.
$$ I know that this integral converges when
$$\frac{3}{s} - 1 > 0$$ giving us an upper bound for $s$ as 3.That is$$s<3$$
I want to know the lower bound of $s$ as for me it must be 0. That is $$s>0$$ as photons having linear dispersion relation also form BEC.
But there is a one of the toughest exams in india known as CSIR NET who have given its answer as $s>1$ which doesnot make sense to me. So kindly let me know which one makes sense?

Photons don't Bose  condense, as their number is not conserved.

I agree that the integral is only divergent between $0 < s < 3$, and nothing special happens at $s=1$.  But what does $s > 0$ have to do with photon?

$s>0$ includes $s=1$ but $s>1$ doesnot.for bosons $s=1$ as$E=pc$

First of all, photons don't undergo BEC, as pointed out by @Buzz.  And then, even if we accept your photon argument, all you can deduce is that the lower bound is smaller than 1.  It can be 0.9999999999999999999 for all you know.  It is in fact 0, but you have to work harder to prove it.

Photons do not form BEC. But particles with $\epsilon(p)\sim p$ probably do. If I remember correctly, BEC in a harmonic potential in optical lattices is mathematically equivalent to the condensation of particles with a linear dependence of energy on momentum. So I think it's an interesting question, although perhaps it's not perfectly worded.

@Gec i jus want to know the lower limit of $s$.please clearify it to me whether it should be 0 or 1.i mean to ask whether it should be $s>0$ or $s>1$.And are there some particles with mass who have linear dispersion relation?

@JazzKhan The thing is that I also don't know why CSIR NET accepts $s > 1$ as correct answer and would like to know.
